# Contact form do not find submit.php file

Tags: contact

I added a contact form to the footer. Apparently it works fine in the main page, but if I go to any of the categories, lets say myblog.com/category/, the contact form is looking for submit.php at myblog.com/category/submit.php. Where I should put physically submit.php in order for contact form to find it in any category page?

Comment: This is not a WordPress question. Please ask Wordpress specific questions here or rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just from what you described it seems as if your `<form>` tag looks more or less like this:

```
<form method='post' action='submit.php'>
```

Try replacing it with:

```
<form method='post' action='http://www.mydomain.com/submit.php'>
```

Comment: a very good point, but it did not work. The same effect.

Comment: How about with `<form method="post" action="<?php get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/submit.php">` or `<form method="post" action="<?php get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/submit.php">` essentially it needs to be the exact path to the submit.php file.

Comment: submit.php is under mydomain.com/submit.php, so I added this "<form method='post' action='<?php get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/submit.php'>"  at it still not working on pages (it works with main page). You can inspect yourself at reprezenta.us.lt (the form in the footer)

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you contact form is... if (As i imagain) its in your template folder you can use this to create an absolute path to it:

```
<form method='post' action='<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/submit.php'>
```

If you places your "submit.php" in the top folder of your hosting account you
should use the same but without the "template" like so..

```
<form method='post' action='<?php get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/submit.php'>
```

.
To help you understand:

```
<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?> = www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/
<?php get_bloginfo('url'); ?> = www.domain.com
```

.
Hope this helps.
Cheers, Sagive

Comment: submit.php is under mydomain.com/submit.php, so I added this "<form method='post' action='<?php get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/submit.php'>"  at it still not working on pages (it works with main page). You can inspect yourself at reprezenta.us.lt (the form in the footer)

Comment: i see.. so. your form is not a part of your wordpress theme... so it wont understand the command bloginf().. might i ask why dont you use CONTACT FORM 7 ??